# Understanding statements in C

Tags: c, variables, types, variable-assignment

I am going through some C codes. Some of them are a little difficult to understand. For instance, what does following assignment do:

```
MY_TYPE my_var[3]={0};
```

`MY_TYPE` is some fixed point arithmetic type. I have not yet come across variables with `[]` brackets and assignment with `{}` around values.

That was too easy, I guess. So, what's advantage of defining

```
my_type my_var[3]={0};
```

over this:

```
my_type my_var[3];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It creates an array `my_var` of type `MY_TYPE` that is of size 3 and is initialised to all 0s (I suspect `MY_TYPE` is some sort of integer type). Note that only one initialisation is necessary for the rest to be init`ed too.

Also note that if you declare the array globally as opposed to within a block, then it will be initialised automatically and this `MY_TYPE my_var[3];` will be enough.

Comment: I've deleted my answer... what you said was correct... a little nuance I didn't know about, thanks for correcting me. I think it would be a nice addition to your answer here...

Answer (score 4):

It's an array of 3 elements all initialized to 0.

Answer (score 2):

`MY_TYPE my_var[3]={0};` initializes the array `my_var` as:

my_var[0] = 0;
my_var[1] = 0;
my_var[2] = 0;

Answer (score 2):

it's 1 dimensional Array of 3 Elements, initialized to 0. Technically, when you initialize one element of array, all other elements are automatically initialized to 0.

So 3 elements with 3 indexes:

```
my_var[0]=0;
my_var[1]=0;
my_var[2]=0;
```

`My_TYPE` can be `int`, `char` or any other data type.
I hope this helps.

Read about Arrays more here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/

Answer (score 1):

`my_var[3]` is a variable of type `MY_TYPE` which can store three values of same type(and known as *Array*) .
Braces `{}` are used here as **initializer**. `my_var[3] = {0}` initializes its first element to `0`.Rest of them are initialized to zero by self.

```
 MY_TYPE  my_var[3];
```

reserves three spaces in memory for the data of `MY_TYPE`. Whereas;

```
 MY_TYPE  my_var[3] = {0};
```

initializes all all these three spaces to `0`.

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of using

```
my_type my_var[3]={0};
```

over

```
my_type my_var[3];
```

is that the first statement initializes the array. Without the initializer, your array will contain garbage values (whatever happened to be in those memory locations previously).

Comment: "Without the initializer, your array will contain garbage values" - unless it was declared globally.

Comment: No problem, things can get a little tricky when it comes to what is initialised by default and what not.